# Cross Validation with Artificial Neural Network in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras

I needed to use cross-validation in the Neural network.
I used

```
 kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
```

and

```
  for train_index, test_index in kf.split(train):
    train_X, train_y = train_XX[train_index], train_yy[train_index]
```

but I couldn't manage to run. One of the errors I see is

```
ValueError: Cannot have number of splits n_splits=5 greater than the number of samples: n_samples=2.
```

I would be glad to have your suggestions if you ever tried CV with in Neural network.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the error is, `KFold` only detects two samples in your `train` variable, which you cannot split into five folds. Make sure you have enough samples or use less splits.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your `train` variable in `kf.split(train):` is a list of two lists e.g. train_x and train_y or something similar. I am guessing this because the KFold API is only detecting only two entries in it, which it is unable to partition in 5 subsets (folds).